# How can I match data to be inserted into my ComboBox in C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, combobox

```
<root>
    <Bathing>
        <Id>San100</Id>
        <name>Santoor</name>
        <AvailProducts>30</AvailProducts>
        <Cost>20.00</Cost>
    </Bathing>
    <Bathing>
        <Id>Det123</Id>
        <name>Dettol</name>
        <AvailProducts>30</AvailProducts>
        <Cost>15.00</Cost>
    </Bathing>
    <Bathing>
        <Id>Rex123</Id>
        <name>Rexona</name>
        <AvailProducts>30</AvailProducts>
        <Cost>16.00</Cost>
    </Bathing>
</root>
```

I am new to C# and XML. Here I am using XML as a data table.

How can I insert only Name elements into my `ComboBox`?

Comment: Your XML is far from readable. Ever hear of indentation?

Comment: Use xlinq to grab the collection of names and bind with your combobox.

Comment: did you try comboBox.DisplayMember = "name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dataset and then read XML file through dataset and then bind combo box to dataset.Set display member to "name".

```
string myXMLfile = @"C:\MySchema.xml";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    // Create new FileStream with which to read the schema.
    System.IO.FileStream fsReadXml = new System.IO.FileStream 
        (myXMLfile, System.IO.FileMode.Open);

        ds.ReadXml(fsReadXml);
        combobox1.DataSource = ds;
        combobox1.Displaymember="name";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ2XML..Its **COOL**

Use `System.Xml.Linq` library

```
XElement doc=XElement.Load("yourXML.xml"); 
var yourList=doc.Descendants("Bathing").Select(x=>x.Element("name").Value);
```

yourList now contains all the names

```
foreach (var name in yourList )
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(name);
        }
```

Comment: what is the namespce for XElement

Comment: @rangasathish use System.Xml.Linq

Answer (score 0):

```
BindingSource bs=new BindingSource;    
DataTable dt=new DataTable;    
bs.DataSource=dt;    
Combobox1.Displaymember="name";
```